# Where can I store JSDoc typedef information to share across projects?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm adding `@typedef` JSDoc comments to the top of Javascript files to help define types (really, so that I can take advantage of some of the typescript benefits without learning it all today).

Where can I store JSDoc typedef information to share across projects in VSCode?

For example, can I store this in some external file and then use it in multiple `.js` files?

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} SomeType
 * @property {String} id
 */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put that code snippet in a `.js` file and then either add it to the `files` or `include` in each `tsconfig.json` file or use a reference directive:

```
///<reference path="path/to/shared-file.js" />
```

(These are the same two options you have for TypeScript declaration files.)  It gets a little more complicated if your shared file is an ES6 module (with top-level ES6 imports or exports); then you'll need to either import it or use [import types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#import-types).